# Error when inserting beers into beer table with T-SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, database-design, sql-insert

I am trying to insert 7 different types of beer into a table I created called Beers using T-SQL. I keep getting errors in my VALUES however with the message:

The following error occured while executing the query:

```
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.
```

Is there something I am missing? I cannot figure out what the error is.

Here is my SQL

--Add Beers to Database

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Beers] ON

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 1)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType],    [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (1, 'Black_Butte', '$9.00', 'porter', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 2)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType],  [BeerRating],  [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (2, 'Corona', '$5.00', 'lager', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 3)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType], [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (3, 'Duvel', '$12.00', 'pale ale', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 4)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType], [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (4, 'Guinness', '$7.00', 'stout', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 5)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType], [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (5, 'Heineken', '$6.00', 'lager', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 6)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType], [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (6, 'Pilsner_Urquell', '$6.50', 'pilsner', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 7)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType], [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (7, 'Stone', '$10.00', 'IPA', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Beers] OFF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing parenthesis before the VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType], [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity]) VALUES
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank you for that! It helps to have a second set of eyes look at something after a long night of working. I'll mark this down as answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing Bracket and added extra comma at the end of every `INSERT` Statement...

Change like below, it will work,

**FROM**

```
,[DateLastActivity],
 VALUES (1, 'Black_Butte', '$9.00', 'porter', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')
```

**TO**

```
,[DateLastActivity])
 VALUES (1, 'Black_Butte', '$9.00', 'porter', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [BeerId] FROM [dbo].[Beers] WHERE [BeerId] = 1)
 INSERT INTO ([dbo].[Beers] ([BeerId], [BeerName], [BeerPricePerBottle], [BeerType],    [BeerRating], [Enabled], [DateInserted],[DateLastActivity])
 VALUES (1, 'Black_Butte', '$9.00', 'porter', NULL, 1, '20071111', '20071111')